# Fetch a list in a @OneToMany association?

Tags: database, jpa, relational-database, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

The thing is, an `user` has one or more `properties`, so that's why is this way my entity class `user`

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

        // others attributes  

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Property
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Property> properties;
    ..
}
```

My entity `property`:

```
@Entity
public class Property implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  ..
  //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="id_user")
  private User user;
  ..
}
```

These entities was generated by `EclipseLink`.

And here are my tables, which I think are ok for what I want.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ..
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
  KEY `u_id_city_to_ac_id_idx` (`id_city`),
  KEY `u_id_state_to_as_id_idx` (`id_state`),
  KEY `u_id_country_to_acy_id_idx` (`id_country`),
  CONSTRAINT `u_id_city_to_ac_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_city`) REFERENCES `address_city` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `u_id_country_to_acy_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_country`) REFERENCES `address_country` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `u_id_state_to_as_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_state`) REFERENCES `address_state` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='an user can be a tenant and a landlord also';
```

And my `property` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `property` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
   ..
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `p_id_accomodation_to_pac_id_idx` (`id_accomodation`),
  KEY `p_id_room_type_to_prt_id_idx` (`id_room_type`),
  KEY `p_id_bed_type_to_pbt_id_idx` (`id_bed_type`),
  KEY `p_id_policty_cancelation_to_pc_id_idx` (`id_policy_cancelation`),
  KEY `p_id_user_to_u_id_idx` (`id_user`),
  KEY `p_id_city_to_ac_id_idx` (`id_city`),
  KEY `p_id_state_to_as_id_idx` (`id_state`),
  KEY `p_id_country_to_acy_id_idx` (`id_country`),
  CONSTRAINT `p_id_accomodation_to_pac_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_accomodation`) REFERENCES `property_accomodation` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `p_id_bed_type_to_pbt_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_bed_type`) REFERENCES `property_bed_type` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `p_id_city_to_ac_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_city`) REFERENCES `address_city` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `p_id_country_to_acy_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_country`) REFERENCES `address_country` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `p_id_policty_cancelation_to_pc_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_policy_cancelation`) REFERENCES `policy_cancellation` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `p_id_room_type_to_prt_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_room_type`) REFERENCES `property_room_type` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `p_id_state_to_as_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_state`) REFERENCES `address_state` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `p_id_user_to_u_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I would like to fetch all `properties` of `user` in a login action for instance:

```
user = userEAO.find(user.getEmail());
user.getProperties(); //always empty
```

How can I do that ? I thought that putting which type of `fetching` was enought but it seems it is not.

**update**
I change to `LAZY` my `FetchType`, look now:

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Property
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List properties;

When the `user` log in the system :

```
User u = userEAO.findByEmail(profile.getEmail());
if (u != null){
  if (u.getProperties() != null){
    u.getProperties().size();
    System.out.println(u.getProperties().size()); // now prints 1
}
```

**James**, when creating a new `property` to the `user` is this what you mean, `refreshing` the object `property`, right ? And yes, after creating this `property` I add it into `user` list `properties` =]

```
public Message create(Property property) {
        try{
            em.persist(property);
            em.flush();
            em.refresh(property);
        }catch(ConstraintViolationException cve){
            cve.printStackTrace();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // 1062 : duplicate entry
            if (e.getMessage().contains("Duplicate"))
                return new Message(-1000);
            else{
                e.printStackTrace();
                return new Message(-1);
            }
        }
        return new Message(0);
    }
```

Comment: There's no need to add tags to your titles, there's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Comment: Try to refresh the entity, then access the collection.  If that works, it means you haven't maintained both sides of your bidirectional relationships, which corrupts the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FetchType.EAGER` means that your `Property` list will be retrieved at same time than the object. `LAZY` means that your list will be retrieved as soon as you will call `getProperties().anyMethod()`. On condition however that your `User` object is stil managed by JPA (means that it currently exist an instance of `EntityManager` managing your entity instance).

The interest of eager is that you will be able to access your list even if the `EntityManager`has been closed (cause your underlying transaction has been closed for example). The one of lazy that you don't execute a query and map objects in memory until they are effectively used

So in your case if the list is empty it's not related to fetch mode (you explicitly call the getProperties() as soon as you've retrieved the User) but it's because you have no data in DB or something fail in your mapping.

Comment: Actually, lazy loading will happen as soon as you call a method on the list returned by getProperties(). Just calling getProperties() won't trigger lazy-loading.

Comment: @Gab, I update my post with my relations and tables, what you think could be wrong there ?

Comment: @JBNizet, should I user `getProperties.get(0)` for instance, to load my `properties` then ?

Comment: yes he's right i forgot. U're looking it using debugger aren't you ? getSize() can make the job too

Comment: sorry dude, I'm having some problem to debug my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006027/how-use-debug-with-eclipse-glassfish-3, but I will see your approach right away.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that when you persist your User object you have set is properties.  When you persist a new Property ensure you set its User and add the Property to the User's properties.  You need to maintain both sides of a bi-directional relationship.

You could also try executing a refresh().